# Necesito alinear 2 <p> con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Buen día, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-black">¿No tienes cuenta?</p>
    <p class=""><a href="cuenta.html" target="_blank">Crear cuenta</a></p>
</div>
```

Necesito alinear los dos `<p>` de manera horizontal. Agradezco la colaboración.

Comment: No entiendo lo que necesitas, replique este código en codepen y realiza lo que requieres utilizando bootstrap =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo hay varios metodos te dejare 2 el primero es directo en el html

```
<div style="display:flex;"> 
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-black">¿No tienes cuenta?</p> 
    <p class=""><a href="cuenta.html" target="_blank">Crear cuenta</a></p> 
</div>
```

Y el otro es con el mismo div le asignas una clase y le agregas el CSS

```
.alinear{
    display:flex;
    }
```

Y el html le agregas la clase

```
<div style="display:flex;"> 
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-black">¿No tienes cuenta?</p> 
    <p class=""><a href="cuenta.html" target="_blank">Crear cuenta</a></p> 
</div>
```

Ambos metodos son gracias a la propiedad display flex ya tu usa los estilos que desees necesarios como el padding o margin. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas para alinear objetos puedes utilizar varios metodos como por ejemplo:

1. Utilizar el atributo align

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE>
   <html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
         <p align="center"> hola</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Utilizar el [w3.css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.asp) descargar el archivo de el link, poner en el head **link rel="stylesheet" href= "localizacion del archivo"** y luego poner un class que se llame w3-center

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE>
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
   </head>
   <body>
         <p class="w3-center"> hola</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-black">¿No tienes cuenta?</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
      <p class=""><a href="cuenta.html" target="_blank">Crear cuenta</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```